# Show fragment inside viewpager from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Hello I'm developing an android app using 3 Fragments (Fragment A, B, C) inside viewpager and tabs, the viewpager works fine. The fragment A contains a List View, when the user clicks a item, the app open a Fragment Dialog with information about the item selected. This dialog has a button called "Add to favorites". Now I want to do this when user press button:

1. close the fragment dialog
2. show the fragment B inside the view pager
3. send the information from dialog fragment to fragment B

How can I do this?

This is part of my code:

*** MainFragmentActivity *** (This works fine)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tube);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });


    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            FragmentA a = new FragmentA();
            Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
            args1.putInt(FragmentA.ARG_SECTION_NAME , position + 1);
            a.setArguments(args1);
            return a;

        case 1:
            FragmentB b= new FragmentB();
            Bundle args2 = new Bundle();
            args2.putInt(FragmentB.ARG_SECTION_NAME , position + 2);
            b.setArguments(args2);
            return b;

        case 2:
            FragmentC c= new FragmentC();
            Bundle args3 = new Bundle();
            args3.putInt(FragmentC.ARG_SECTION_NAME , position + 3);
            c.setArguments(args3);
            return c;

          default:
              return null;
        }
    }
```

This is the Fragment Dialog

*** FragmentDialogView ***

```
public class FragmentDialogView extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 0;
private String videoId;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle mArgs = getArguments();

    View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_view, container, false);

    //Buttons
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE) {

    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_one:

            //Here it should show the fragment B inside the viewpager

        break;
    default:                
        break;
   }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dismiss the `Dialog` include the following in your `DialogFragment`'s class

```
private Dialog dialog;

@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_one:

            dismiss();

        break;
    default:                
        break;
   }

}
```

And create a **interface**

Create the following **Communicator.java**

```
public interface Communicator {
    public void respond(int i);
}
```

**Implement** this **Communicator** in your **MainAcitvity**

And create a `instance` of this **Communicator** in your **fragment** like this

```
public class FragmentDialogView extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

    private Communicator com;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        com = (Communicator) getActivity();
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn:
            com.respond(1);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Whenever you **click** that **button** *it sends the int to the method which is residing inside the* **MainActivity**

which will look like following

```
@Override
public void respond(int i) {


        // Receive a bundle here
        // and pass the corresponding information to the FragmentB
        // here i'm receving an int and pass it to the FragmentB as a String

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentB fragment = (FragmentB) fm.findFragmentByTag("FragmentB");
        fragment.fromMainActivity(""+i);

        // If the above the one doesn't work keep the instance as Static and then try

        viewPager.invalidate();
        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);

    // Inside the setCuttentItem() method 0 first tab
    // 1 second tab
    // 2 third tab and so on
    }
```

Here I'm receiving an int . You can use a bundle to pass the corresponding information. This will change the `viewPager` to show the next tab as well

and keep any simple method insdie the FragmentB like the following

```
public void fromMainActivity(String sample) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), sample, duration).show();
}
```

I hope this would help :) Happy coding

Comment: Thanks Sha works fine, If try to pass information i need create another instance to FragmentB? If i create a Bundle at OnActivityCreated this will get Null because when the app start the bundle for this fragment doesn't have any value

Comment: Yes. you need to create a instance if it doesn't work, try make it as a `static`. you're going to create the bundle from the `DialogFrament` rite. so it won't be null if you're passing anything. otherwise check a condition there for null @deleon

Answer (score 2):

1.Try this : getDialog().dismiss();

2.As I understood correctly, create a method like this in your fragment ,

```
public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text){
    FirstFragment f= new FirstFragment();
    return f;
}
```

Call it in your button `onClick()` such as `FirstFragment.newInstance("Fragment, Instance 1");`

3.Create `Interface` with the method in your DialogFragment can call to pass any data you want back to Fragment that created said DialogFragment. Also set your Fragment as target such as  `myFragmentDialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0)`. Then in dialog, get your target fragment object with getTargetFragment() and cast to interface you created. Now you can pass the data using `((MyInterface)getTargetFragment()).methodToPassData(data)`. 
For more info : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579590/how-to-send-data-from-dialogfragment-to-a-fragment)

Comment: I did that... look my first class. i dont have problems with the fragments in the view pager, my question is how can I show the position B (Fragment) when the user press the button inside Dialog Fragment

Comment: Did you try the  suggested solution, calling the given method inside your button onClick() ?

Comment: I have use this for similar kind of scenario. What I mean here is, create a new instance of your fragment B when you press the button. Did you get any error?