# How to add Fragment from Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog

How can I add a Fragment from a dialog (not DialogFragment)? I have been following steps from http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html and other link I found on google, but it always crash. If it is not possible, is there any alternative?

Update: logcat

```
E/FragmentManager﹕ No view found for id 0x7f030032 (com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:layout/fragment_xxx) for fragment xxxFragment{20f8e3bb #1 id=0x7f030032}
E/FragmentManager﹕ Activity state:
E/FragmentManager﹕ Local FragmentActivity 3cfe20d8 State:
E/FragmentManager﹕ mCreated=truemResumed=true mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
E/FragmentManager﹕ mLoadersStarted=true
E/FragmentManager﹕ FragmentManager misc state:
E/FragmentManager﹕ mActivity=com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx@3cfe20d8
E/FragmentManager﹕ mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@2545fc31
E/FragmentManager﹕ mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
E/FragmentManager﹕ View Hierarchy:
E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{30897f16 V.E..... ... 0,0-768,1184}
E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{30480097 V.E..... ... 0,0-768,1184 #1020378 android:id/decor_content_parent}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.FrameLayout{aa07284 V.E..... ... 0,50-768,1184 #1020002 android:id/content}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{3f4d2a6d VFE..... F.. 0,0-768,1134 #7f080022 app:id/menu_layout}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.FrameLayout{341676a2 V.E..... ... 0,0-768,1134 #7f080023 app:id/content_frame}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.RelativeLayout{29020f33 V.E..... ... 0,0-768,1134 #7f080040 app:id/rlRootView}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.PhotoView{af432f0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-768,1134 #7f080041 app:id/pv_background}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{271f0069 V.E..... ... 0,160-768,457}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{14895aee V.ED.... ... 345,0-422,137 #7f080042 app:id/iv_location}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{1a446b8f V.E..... ... 0,147-768,297}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{7818e1c V.ED.... ... 218,6-549,80 #7f080043 app:id/tv_current_location}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{311e3a25 V.ED.... ... 271,80-497,130 #7f080044 app:id/tv_current_location_sub}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{3d3437fa V.E..... ... 0,879-768,1134}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{3da631ab V.E..... ... 0,76-255,139}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{38277008 V.ED.... ... 0,0-255,37}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{1b1d53a1 V.ED.... ... 0,37-255,63}
E/FragmentManager﹕ [ 08-05 18:12:10.349 26212:26212 E/FragmentManager ]
    android.view.View{a7dd9c6 V.ED.... ... 255,30-257,205}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{5143d87 V.E...C. ... 257,0-512,215 #7f080045 app:id/linear_xxx_button}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{31c784b4 V.ED.... ... 38,0-216,178 #7f080046 app:id/iv_restaurant}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{139a88dd V.ED.... ... 0,178-255,215}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.view.View{266dcc52 V.ED.... ... 512,30-514,205}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{2a6d2b23 V.E..... ... 514,76-768,139}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{13b23820 V.ED.... ... 0,0-254,37}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{38bbd5d9 V.ED.... ... 0,37-254,63}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.FrameLayout{21f85b9e I.E..... ... -480,0-0,1134 #7f080024 app:id/menu_fragment}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{1cdd567f V.E..... ... 0,0-480,1134}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ListView{1fd2b64c VFED..C. ... 0,0-480,1134 #7f0800c0 app:id/menu_list}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.RelativeLayout{b0af695 V.E..... ... 0,0-480,592 #7f0800c7 app:id/root_container}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{170a93aa V.ED.... ... 140,0-340,140 #7f0800de app:id/iv_logo}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{27fadb9b V.ED.... ... 170,226-310,366 #7f0800df app:id/menu_item_login_fb}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{299aeb38 V.ED.... ... 106,482-374,592 #7f0800e0 app:id/menu_item_login_text}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.RelativeLayout{ff16711 V.E..... ... 0,591-480,683 #7f0800c7 app:id/root_container}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{1f564076 V.ED.... ... 120,21-170,71 #7f0800dc app:id/menu_item_icon}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{30a19677 V.ED.... ... 202,21-298,71 #7f0800dd app:id/menu_item_text}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.RelativeLayout{7af82e4 V.E..... ... 0,682-480,774 #7f0800c7 app:id/root_container}
E/FragmentManager﹕ [ 08-05 18:12:10.351 26212:26212 E/FragmentManager ]
    android.widget.ImageView{1ff4634d V.ED.... ... 120,21-170,71 #7f0800dc app:id/menu_item_icon}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{2bddee02 V.ED.... ... 202,21-380,71 #7f0800dd app:id/menu_item_text}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.RelativeLayout{238f2313 V.E..... ... 0,773-480,865 #7f0800c7 app:id/root_container}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{3453e950 V.ED.... ... 120,21-170,71 #7f0800dc app:id/menu_item_icon}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{1cb0e749 V.ED.... ... 202,21-202,71 #7f0800dd app:id/menu_item_text}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.RelativeLayout{940e84e V.E..... ... 0,864-480,956 #7f0800c7 app:id/root_container}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{31bedd6f V.ED.... ... 120,21-170,71 #7f0800dc app:id/menu_item_icon}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{8964a7c V.ED.... ... 202,21-202,71 #7f0800dd app:id/menu_item_text}
E/FragmentManager﹕ [ 08-05 18:12:10.352 26212:26212 E/FragmentManager ]
    android.widget.RelativeLayout{a97af05 V.E..... ... 0,955-480,1047 #7f0800c7 app:id/root_container}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{1cc73b5a V.ED.... ... 120,21-170,71 #7f0800dc app:id/menu_item_icon}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{3685e18b V.ED.... ... 202,21-202,71 #7f0800dd app:id/menu_item_text}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.RelativeLayout{3e3b9268 V.E..... ... 0,1046-480,1138 #7f0800c7 app:id/root_container}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{a693681 V.ED.... ... 120,21-170,71 #7f0800dc app:id/menu_item_icon}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{262db326 V.ED.... ... 202,21-202,71 #7f0800dd app:id/menu_item_text}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{236f0b67 V.E..... ... 0,1134-480,1134 #7f0800c1 app:id/menu_logout}
E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{246b6d14 V.ED.... ... 0,50-768,146 #1020379 android:id/action_bar_container}
E/FragmentManager﹕ [ 08-05 18:12:10.352 26212:26212 E/FragmentManager ]
    com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{2e71b9bd V.E..... ... 0,0-768,96 #102037a android:id/action_bar}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{1231dbb2 VFE...C. ... 17,0-71,96}
E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{dd6f703 V.E..... ... 0,0-54,96}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{331c4680 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102003b android:id/up}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{278534b9 V.ED.... ... 8,33-46,63 #102002c android:id/home}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.RelativeLayout{29de00fe V.E..... ... 112,0-656,96}
E/FragmentManager﹕ xxx.xxx.xxx.view.FontTextView{3a48005f G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0800c4 app:id/actionbar_title}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{293f4aac V.E..... ... 214,12-329,84 #7f0800c5 app:id/actionbar_title_image}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{5bb6375 V.ED.... ... 8,12-115,72}
E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ActionMenuView{2a952f0a V.ED.... ... 656,0-768,96}
E/FragmentManager﹕ [ 08-05 18:12:10.353 26212:26212 E/FragmentManager ]
    com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView{196437b VF.D..CL ... 0,0-112,96 #0}
E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{21ac6598 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #102037b android:id/action_context_bar}
E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{8ebc1f1 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #102037c android:id/split_action_bar}
08-05 18:12:10.353  26212-26212/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, PID: 26212
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030032 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:layout/fragment_xxx) for fragment xxxFragment{20f8e3bb #1 id=0x7f030032}
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:886)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: share your logcat error

Comment: post the code you tried along with log

Answer (score 0):

You should not add fragment from dialog directly, but instead you should call the activity/fragment that started this dialog to do that instead (optionally passing fragment instance to add).

If you do not know how to pass data from dialog, here's older answer of mine you may find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18579638/1235698