# Android NavigationView change title onBackPressed

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

I have a `NavigationView` that changes certain `Fragment` by clicking on its item and  setting `toolbar`'s title with  item's name:

```
fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.studying:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, studyFragment).addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case R.id.events:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, eventsFragment).addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case R.id.discount:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, discountsFragment).addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case R.id.bookmarks:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, bookmarksFragment).addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, settingsFragment).addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case R.id.prolong_sign:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, prolongFragment).addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case R.id.contacts:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, contactsFragment).addToBackStack(null);
            break;
    }
    toolbarTitle.setText(item.getTitle().toString());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Proving better usability I `override` `onBackPressed`  method:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 && fm.getBackStackEntryCount() != 1) {
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();
        } else if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            toolbarTitle.setText("TEST");
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

If I back to the first `Fragment`, my `toolbarTitle` sets okay according to:

```
 else if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            toolbarTitle.setText("TEST");
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();
        }
```

But I don't know how to make toolbarTitle to change title correctly on each `onBackPressed` and make previous item in `NavigationView` checked. Can you help me with it?

**EDIT**

I created an interface

```
public interface OnToolbarTitle {
void setTitle(String title);
```

}

implemented it `MainActivity` and overrided

```
 @Override
public void setTitle(String title) {
    toolbarTitle.setText(title);
}
```

And  tried  to use it in Fragments by attaching it in Fragments:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    titleSetter = (OnToolbarTitle) context;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    titleSetter.setTitle("Test-frag3");
}
```

But I got `NullPointerException` in line with `setTitle()` method.

**EDIT**

Ok I solved my problem by accessing Toolbar in fragment.

```
    View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    title.setText("study lol");
```

Still, I'd be glad to see, how can I achive it with interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider making your fragments setting the title. I.e. define interface like:

```
interface HostContract {
    setTitle(String title);
}
```

and make your activity implement it. Then in each fragment you should call `((HostContract)getActivity).setTitle()` in fragment's `onResume()`. This way you set the title when your fragment goes into game (be it because it is newly added, or because you took previous one from backstack, which should solve your problem. And that's basically all you need to do.

Comment: I believe that you direct me to right way, but I'm not sure, that I know enough about interfaces. I changed my post.

Comment: You may want to read this [How to send data from DialogFragment to a Fragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18579638/1235698) for more detailed instruction.

Comment: Thank you, Marcin!

Answer (score 0):

your if...else should be like

```
if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 && fm.getBackStackEntryCount() != 1) {
        fm.popBackStackImmediate();
        toolbarTitle.setText("TEST");
 } else if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
        toolbarTitle.setText("TEST");
        fm.popBackStackImmediate();
 } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

Comment: How do I know what `Fragment` is active? :)))))