# Change fragment options menu after user sets a value in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a `Fragment` **A** which shows a `MenuItem` **Mi** in the toolbar. On clicking **Mi**, I am showing a `DialogFragment` **Df** to the user to set a value **V**.

I am passing this value to fragment **A** by implementing a callback listener interface.
Once the value is set, I want to hide **Mi** from toolbar menu of fragment **A**.

I wanted to handle this inside `onPause()` and `onResume()` of fragment **A**, but showing a DialogFragment doesn't change the lifecycle of fragment. I was wondering how to approach this problem.

How can I achieve this thing?

Comment: simply put, you want to hide Mi when Df is dismissed after user sets value V?

Comment: you can try with shared-preferences I think. set a flag to your menu's active/inactive state, and compare with it to show or hide the Mi

Comment: @Mercato Yes I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using a callback listener in my fragment **A** which listens to DialogFragment **Df**. Once the value **V** is set, this callback method in **A** is invoked. Inside this method, I am using **V** and setting a flag to indicate **V** has been set and then calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

Refer this for implementing your own callback.
[How to send data from DialogFragment to a Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579590/how-to-send-data-from-dialogfragment-to-a-fragment)

```
public void myCallback(int V){
  //Use V according to my logic
   vIsSet = Boolean.TRUE;
   getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    if(vIsSet) {
        menu.removeItem(MENU_ITEM_ID);//item id of Mi
    }
}
```