# How do I pass a boolean value from a DialogFragment to another Fragment in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to make it so a clear button will open up an alert dialog which has a yes or no. When clicking the yes button, it should pass a bool value from the dialog frag to the other frag. If the value is true, which it should be when yes is clicked, it will call methods which will clear a database. Here is the dialog frag and the part of the frag where I'm trying to implement it. I can't get the dialog box to appear, but so far it does make the screen darker which I assume means I'm not hooking it up right.

Dialog frag:

```
public class DialogClear extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clear_dialog, null);
        final Button yes = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.yes);
        final Button no = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.no);

        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

Here is how I'm trying to call it from my frag

```
       clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialogClear = new DialogClear();
                dialogClear.setTargetFragment(BloodPressureFragment.this, 1);
                dialogClear.show(getFragmentManager(),"");

                    dataManager.clearDatabase();
                    dataManager.createDatabase();
                    dataText.setText("");
                    dataText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no_border);
                    updateList();
                }

        });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send data from DialogFragment to a Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579590/how-to-send-data-from-dialogfragment-to-a-fragment)

Comment: @Shashanth So do I create the interface inside the Dialog frag?

Comment: Interface file you can create anywhere inside the project. You have to implement that interface inside caller activity/fragment. When you done with the job in your dialog fragment, pass the required value to the implementing method.

Comment: ViewModel's can easily solve this problem and it will retain data even on Orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to code party

you have many choices to do this job, but i will show you best way for using fragments.

As you know, all fragments changes in one activity and extend from it.

So the easy way is this:

> 1.build public fields in your activity
>
> 2.build a getInstant method on activity
>
> 3.fill and get values of that activity from any fragments that you want show on this

see this example:

```
public boolean isLocationOn;
```

this field is build in activity
now:
in any fragment:

```
MainActivity.getInstance().isLocationOn = true;
```

in other fragment:

```
if(MainActivity.getInstance().isLocationOn){

 //todo show map or ...
}
```

in this way you can use anything in fragments

update me in comments

Comment: how will you retain the data if orientation is changed?

Comment: when orientation change, onViewCreate called in fragment and u can do this job and calling in there

Comment: Activity instance will die and data attached to it will also get destroyed. You can save ur primitive/serialised data in bundle `onSaveInstanceState` but still the complex data still need's to be persisted in a DB or in android file system.So to solve all of the problem's and to keep the state of the application alive ViewModel's are best solution.

Comment: when orientation changed, view will create again and data in activity never lose.watch the lifecycle of activity with fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You should read and try using 3 thing's to solve this.

#### 1. [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

- easy to navigate to fragment's and DialogFragment

---

#### 2. [View Model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=Cj0KCQiA2b7uBRDsARIsAEE9XpFRl96uCV2dbYoCXqRBUhfkJWDrxnlrPtG9xzxX03h-f0qDhGpKs3caAqRqEALw_wcB)

- Share same View Model between different fragment's of an activity
- Data is not lost on Orientation change's
- All business logic at one place and easy to unit test

---

#### 3. [Live Data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

- recommended for responsive ui
- Easy to understand Api's